# Analytics Connection in Qlik Sense - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, machine-learning, server-side, qliksense

I'm working with Qlik's advanced analytics integration providing a server side extension (SSE) for Qlik Sense built using Python.

There is a Qlik-Py-Init.bat where a Python virtual environment was set up, some packages being installed and TCP Port 50055 being opened for inbound communication. So, to start this Python service I should run Qlik-Py-Start.bat file.

But I'm getting a problem with the connection between Python and Qlik.

Everytime I try to start the virtual environmnet the following message appears:

```
  "Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "__main__.py", line 16, in <module> import ServerSideExtension_pb2 
   as SSE File "C:\Users\ssgabriel\Desktop\Projeto Qlik Mart\qlik-py-tools-3.9\qlik-py-env\generated\ServerSideExtension_pb2.py", line 6, in <module> from google.protobuf.internal import enum_type_wrapper 
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'"
```

Project Tutorial link: https://developer.qlik.com/garden/5af5217ab2606a3c2c1f4d1d?_ga=2.233199326.1596669125.1553511020-1486733373.1550746062

I expect the output connection between Python and Qlik is established and see the capabilities listed in the terminal (Correlations, Clustering, Forecasting etc)

Answer (score 1):

Nabeel from Qlik has developed and shared his solution to this. I found it easy to setup and it is working well. https://github.com/nabeel-oz/qlik-py-tools

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved: I removed the pip and it solved my problem as well. After that I installed and upgraded a new version of pip and all the problems disappered.

Update 04/04/2019

Some Tips: If you're in a Windows environment don't forget to configure the C++ Compiler, all environment variable and versioning packages. Depending on the Python version may appears some errors